# javascript: How to clean an input box when another input value changed?

Tags: javascript

I made one input (#child)auto suggestion base on another input(#parent). When the #parent input value changed, I want to clean the #child's value. I would like to learn how to do this, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to the `onchange` event of the parent and then clear the value of the child:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // the document has loaded => we could access the DOM
    // we subscribe to the onchange event pf the parent:
    document.getElementById('parentId').onchange = function() {
        // and when this event is triggered we clean the child
        // element value
        document.getElementById('childId').value = '';
    };
};
```